# How do I specify an IN clause in laravel backpack?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-backpack

How do I add an `IN` clause in laravel with backpack?

This is what I am looking for:

```
$this->crud->addClause('where', 'customer_id', 'in', [1,3,5,6,7]);`
```

Should translate into something like this:

```
select * from customer where customer_id in (1,3,5,6,7);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title to specify exactly what you are looking for, and so others can find it easily. I also indented your code by 4 spaces so that it is rendered as code. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `whereIn` instead of `where`, **`backpack-for-laravel`** is ready for that:

```
$this->crud->addClause('whereIn', 'customer_id', [1,3,5,6,7]);
```

Comment: How can you do `whereIn, 'field1'` or `whereIn, 'field2'` ?

Answer (score 0):

select * from customer whereIn (customer_id ,$array);

Comment: No, its not that case, iam using a package called backpack, and inside the controller crud I have to use his features to filter data. its not only laravel.