# Iam trying to use addclause where in (1,2,4,5,6...) in crud controller

Tags: where-clause, crud, laravel-backpack

Iam trying to use addclause, but instead of use a filter in my where that get only one value, I need to use a list of values, like this

$this->crud->addClause('where', 'customer_id', 'in', [1,3,5,6,7]);

Its possible? how to make it happen?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Guilherme, is this some how related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816364/how-do-i-specify-an-in-clause-in-laravel-backpack/52884017#52884017 ?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!